# Deprecated UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap Warning

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

I am getting a warning of deprecated in ios6 when using

```
 label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
```

Is there any other method for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html), use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping to eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 7):

Use `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` instead. The documentation for `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap` points this out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a link to the documentation.

Comment: The documentation literally says "This is deprecated. Use this other thing instead." Which is what I put in my answer. My reference to the documentation was to suggest subtly to the original poster that maybe they should use it first, in the future. But yea... your point is valid.

Comment: is NSLineBreakByCharWrapping safe to use in iOS5?

Comment: @BenClayton: Actually, no. While `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap` is deprecated, you can still use it, especially if you still need to support iOS versions earlier than iOS6. But moving forward, as developers begin dropping support for versions prior to iOS6, use of deprecated methods and such should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping to eliminate the warning.

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```

and for the test alignment use..

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

Happy Coding!!!